# varchar2 to long or long to varchar2

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to perform a filter on a column type 'Long' in oracle SQL.
But it is giving me some error.

My query is

```
select * 
from table 
where longColumn like '%lv%';
```

where 'longColumn' is long type which is generating type error when 'like' used with this.

Is there any way by which above error could be resolved.

Comment: Why are you using `LONG` in the first place? That has been deprecated 15 years ago

Comment: `LONG` behaves in weird way. Most operations you would currently expect to work easily, won't really. Switch to `VARCHAR2` if you can. Otherwise you'll need to try and fail until something works (or not).

Comment: Actually the Database has been designed like this a long time ago and I cannot change it now. I tried so may things but nothing seems to be working. That is why I am looking for help if someone can.